# Angular Ivy In a Library Breaks enableResourceInlining

Tags: angular, angular-cli, viewengine, ng-packagr, angular-ivy

I have created a simple Angular library "test-pub" (using `nx g @nrwl/angular:lib test-pub --publishable`). Then I've added a very basic component to it.

super.component.html:

```
<p>super works!</p>
```

super.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-super',
  templateUrl: './super.component.html'
})
export class SuperComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

In my `tsconfig.json` I've added the following (please note that `enableResourceInlining` is set to `true`:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  }
```

Finally, I've run ng build for this library: `ng run test-pub:build`

Then I looked into the generated code for the library and have found the following:

```
import { ɵɵdefineComponent, ɵɵelementStart, ɵɵtext, ɵɵelementEnd, ɵsetClassMetadata, Component, ɵɵdefineNgModule, ɵɵdefineInjector, ɵɵsetNgModuleScope, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

var SuperComponent = /** @class */ (function () {
    function SuperComponent() {
    }
    SuperComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {
    };
    SuperComponent.ɵfac = function SuperComponent_Factory(t) { return new (t || SuperComponent)(); };
    SuperComponent.ɵcmp = ɵɵdefineComponent({ type: SuperComponent, selectors: [["rd-super"]], decls: 2, vars: 0, template: function SuperComponent_Template(rf, ctx) { if (rf & 1) {
            ɵɵelementStart(0, "p");
            ɵɵtext(1, "super works!");
            ɵɵelementEnd();
        } }, styles: [""] });
    return SuperComponent;
}());
/*@__PURE__*/ (function () { ɵsetClassMetadata(SuperComponent, [{
        type: Component,
        args: [{
                selector: 'rd-super',
                templateUrl: './super.component.html',
                styleUrls: ['./super.component.less']
            }]
    }], function () { return []; }, null); })();

var TestPubModule = /** @class */ (function () {
    function TestPubModule() {
    }
    TestPubModule.ɵmod = ɵɵdefineNgModule({ type: TestPubModule });
    TestPubModule.ɵinj = ɵɵdefineInjector({ factory: function TestPubModule_Factory(t) { return new (t || TestPubModule)(); }, imports: [[CommonModule]] });
    return TestPubModule;
}());
(function () { (typeof ngJitMode === "undefined" || ngJitMode) && ɵɵsetNgModuleScope(TestPubModule, { declarations: [SuperComponent], imports: [CommonModule], exports: [SuperComponent] }); })();
/*@__PURE__*/ (function () { ɵsetClassMetadata(TestPubModule, [{
        type: NgModule,
        args: [{
                imports: [CommonModule],
                declarations: [SuperComponent],
                exports: [SuperComponent]
            }]
    }], null, null); })();

/**
 * Generated bundle index. Do not edit.
 */

export { SuperComponent, TestPubModule };
//# sourceMappingURL=rd-test-pub.js.map
```

Please pay attention to the fact that generated JS file still contains `templateUrl` in `ɵsetClassMetadata(SuperComponent ....`.
Moreover, when I tried to use the library in my JIT Angular app, it threw an error **404: super.component.html** not found. This means that my application was trying to find the asset, it didn't use the inlined template!

During my research I've come to the following issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30174
In there @alxhub explains that indeed `enableResourceInlining` is now ignored and basically resources are  always inlined with Ivy.
I am having two questions here:

1. Why does compiled Ivy code in my example still use `templateUrl` and why is my JIT Angular application still trying to find the HTML asset separately
2. Right now we can easily work around the problem by using `enableIvy: false`. But what to do when older ViewEngine will be dropped and we will be forced to use Ivy?

Comment: Find a solution to this? Same problem.

Comment: @SteveBrush Hi, it's been a long time since I've posted this issue. Basically I moved to aot=true and Ivy in the app which uses the library.